# Why are "1...2" and "1....2" not syntax errors?

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings "all";
use Data::Dumper;

my @abc = (1, 2, 3);

my @bbb = @abc[1..2];
my @ccc = @abc[1...2];
my @ddd = @abc[1....2];

say Dumper "@bbb"; # Output: '2 3'
say Dumper "@ccc"; # Output: '2 3'
say Dumper "@ddd"; # Output: ''
```

Why aren't there any syntax errors in the code above?

What do `1...2` (three dots) and `1....2` (four dots) mean here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`1..2` is tokenized as `1` `..` `2`, and parsed as a [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators) with two integer constant operands. When evaluated, it is evaluated in list context, and it produces the integers from 1 to 2 inclusive.

`1...2` is tokenized as `1` `...` `2`, and parsed as a range operator with two integer constant operands. `...` is different than `..` in scalar context, but they're the same in list context.

`1....2` is tokenized as `1` `...` `.2`, and parsed as a range operator with two constant operands. When evaluated, it is evaluated in list context, and it produces the integers from 1 to 0.2 inclusive, which is to say it produces nothing.

---

A side note:

When tokenizing, Perl normally gobbles up as many characters as it can with no regard as to what follows. One exception is that a `.` will never be included in a numeric literal if followed by another `.`.

This means that `1..2` is always tokenized as `1`, `..`, `2` and never  `1.` `.2` or `1.` `.` `2`.

This means that `1...2` is always tokenized as `1`, `...`, `2` and never  `1.`, `..`, `2` or `1`, `..`, `.2`.

This also means that `1.....2` will never be tokenized as `1.` `...` `.2` even though that would prevent the parser from throwing a syntax error.

(Thanks @Dada for helping me correct this.)

---

A side note:

At least some constant ranges are flattened into an array constant.

`1..2` in list context and `1...2` in list context both compile to a two-element array constant, just like `1, 2`.

`1....2` in list context compiles to an empty array constant.

Comment: See also [Range Operator, in: Perl in a Nutshell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/perl-in-a/1565922867/ch04s05.html#pnut-ch-4-sect-5.11.1)

Answer (score 12):

If you give Perl the option `-MO=Deparse` it will say how Perl parse your code.

The three-dot form `(1...2)` parses as `(1..2)`. This is unexpected to me, but I assume it is a side effect of being able to parse both the two-dot and three-dot forms of the flip-flop operator.

The four-dot form parses as `(1 .. .2)`. This is an empty range, so your array slice is also empty.

Comment: Re "*The three-dot form (1...2) parses as (1..2).*", No. They are parsed differently, but they compile to the same the thing in this case. Specifically, they compile to a constant array of two elements, just like `1, 2`. /// Re "*it will say how Perl parse your code.*", Deparse is a decompiler. It can help show how Perl understand codes, but it doesn't actually show how code is parsed. That's why `1..2`, `1...2` and `1, 2` all Deparse as `1, 2`. (They don't Deparse as `1..2` as you claim.)

Comment: `-MO=Deparse` is really a good thing I haven't used before. It helped me understand the code. Thank you.